# How to delete from a database in Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm sure there are similar questions, but I searched both here and on Google and found no answer.

I have a list of products in the database. And I have a method that delete the current product by button. And it works great!

The problem starts when I try to make the button not POSTBACK

I know the problem is with the RETURN but if I do not write it, I have an error message because my method is - async Task

For what I need to change the method so that it works without changing the URL / postback?

**index.cshtml-**

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-lg list-group-flush list my--4">
@foreach (var prod in Model.ProductList)
{
    <li class="list-group-item px-0">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <span class="avatar avatar-lg">
                    תמונה
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col ml--2">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-1">
                    <a href="#!">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => prod.ProductName)
                    </a>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text small text-muted mb-1">
                    אימייל
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <form method="post">
                    <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Delete" value="Delete" asp-route-id="@prod.Id" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-success="deleteItem(this)" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

**Index.cshtml.cs-**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        Product currentProduct = new Product(); 
        foreach (var item in _context.Products)
        {
            if (item.Id==id)
            {
                currentProduct = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        _context.Products.Remove(currentProduct);
        _context.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToPage("./Index");

    }
```

Comment: So the problem is that your ajax callback is reloading the page? Have you tried returning something other than `RedirectToPage` from the function? Maybe just return a success message, or some kind of JSON

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, we can find that it will return **HTTP 302** redirect response status code while you make AJAX request from client side. Please note that AJAX can not automatically redirect to that page, normally we do not return a redirect response to AJAX client.

As @schwartz721 mentioned, if possible, you can try to modify the handler to return `JsonResult` or `OkResult` etc rather than `RedirectToPage`, then you can handle response in success callback.

Besides, if you indeed want to do AJAX submission and redirect user to index page after user delete a product, you may need to do redirection on client side, like below.

```
window.location.href = url_here;
```